# Issue with pointer arithmetic in my own malloc() function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

I am currently working on implementing my own malloc() function. The one thing that seems to not be working is that I'm unable to correctly return the memory address of the beginning of my current block. My block struct looks like this and is of size 16:

```
typedef struct block {
    size_t size;
    struct block* next;
    struct block* prev;
    int free;
} block_t;
```

My malloc looks like this currently:

```
void *bmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void * mem=0;
    size_t alloc=size;
    if (freelist==0)
    {
        freelist=&heap[0];
        freelist->free=0;
        freelist->prev=0;
        freelist->size=MAX_HEAP_SIZE;
        freelist->next=0;
        //printf("is this happening?");
    }

    for (curr=freelist;curr!=NULL;curr=curr->next)
    {
        if (alloc<=curr->size && curr->free==0)
        {
            block_t *tmp=curr->next;
            curr->free=1;
            curr>size=MAX_HEAP_SIZE;
            curr>next=curr+alloc+sizeof(block_t);
            //curr->next->next=tmp;
            curr->next->size=curr->size-alloc;
            curr->next->free=0;
            curr->next->prev=curr;
            mem=curr+sizeof(block_t)
            return mem;
        }
    }
}
```

`Curr` and `Freelist` are both `block_t` structs. I know the issue must lie in the step where I set `mem=curr+sizeof(block_t)`, but I'm not really sure how to fix it. Upon some checking I noticed that the first allocation of memory returns an address 276 bytes away from the beginning of the array the blocks live on top of, and after the first allocation the blocks memory addresses are 512 bytes away.

Comment: `mem=curr+sizeof(block_t)
                return mem;` is a syntax error. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You may also find useful this [awkwardly written, but good basic malloc introduction](https://github.com/zyfjeff/C-HOW-TO/blob/master/c-malloc/Malloc_tutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do pointer arithmetic, the values are always scaled by the size of the type the pointer points at.  So when you do

```
mem = cur + sizeof(block_t);
```

since `cur` is a `block_t *`, the addition is scaled by `sizeof(block_t)` automatically.  Which means that if `sizeof(block_t)` is 16, this will add 256 bytes to the pointer, which is not what you want.  You probably just want

```
mem = cur + 1;
```

here, and similar changes elsewhere.